# Ejecutar archivo de manera segura

Tags: php

Desde mi código en **PHP** quiero ejecutar otro archivo **PHP**. Para ello utilizo esta línea:

```
    header('Location: proceso.php');
    exit;
```

Cómo puedo ejecutar este archivo de tal manera que sea más seguro y que solamente se ejecute desde esta línea de código?

Comment: pero podras ver el archivo cuando se cumpla que? no entiendo

Comment: Con eso estás redireccionando a ese archivo y no ejecutándolo desde otro. Para que se ejecute desde otro igual te interesa un `include` o `require`. ¿A qué te refieres con "de manera segura"? ¿No es tuyo el archivo PHP?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, quiero redireccionar a ese archivo. Pero a este archivo lo puedo acceder desde la barra del navegador. A eso me refiero con "de manera segura".

Comment: @Piropeator sigo sin entender todavía qué es lo que quieres o a qué te refieres con "de manera segura". ¿Quieres redireccionar a ese archivo pero sin que se pueda acceder a él desde la barra del navegador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola podrias utilizar algo asi al princiio de tu archivo proceso.php, debemos saber si ese proceso lo mandas a llamar desde un submit o boton, o solo quieres incluir su funcionalidad en tu pagina php aqui utilizarias include o require_once.

```
//si tu llamado a este proceso viene de un POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
      Lo que quieres que se ejecute
} else {
      //Redirecciona si quieres entrar por URL
      header('Location: proceso.php');
      exit;
}
```

Saludos!